# I have a stealth nemesis, what to do?

Tags: support, down-votes

I've noticed that someone downvoted seven of my posts in a row.  All of these posts aren't new (at least a month old, but most are much older).  It looks like as if someone looked at my profile and downvoted the posts showing high rating.  While I could understand some downovtes as possibly disagreeing with the content of the answer, in some cases that would be really stretching it.

What I believe is happening is that someone unfamiliar with Emacs, but who knows me from other online interactions (I use the same handle consistently on many different sites) decided to exercise his or her revenge in this way.

I don't really care for karma points, but I am disappointed with this kind of behavior.  Worst yet, I've absolutely no clue as to who and why would do this.

---

I wouldn't seek administrative justice, but I'd like to know who the person is and what did I do to them.

Comment: Normally a row of votes in such a short time would be automatically reversed, but that would have happened already (the automated job runs nightly). Stack Exchange staff may yet reverse the votes if they decide that they were most likely fraudulent (voting for the person rather than the post). But you will not be told who it was.

Comment: It's happened to me before too. And no, there's no way to know who it was. If the points are not reversed and you feel you were significantly harmed by it, we can manually get in touch with staff. Otherwise, just shrug it off and move on.

Comment: @Malabarba nah, it's ok. It's not like something depends on the points I get or don't get. It's just weird to think someone would go into so much trouble, and not know why.